# Do phrases like "the 80s" take singular or plural subject-verb agreement?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which is correct:

1. The 80s **is** returning
2. The 80s **are** returning.

If you say "are returning", then why do we say, "The 80s was a time of....." ?

Answer (score 1):

The eighties referring to a set of years, *plurality* seems most appropriate.

> The eighties *are* returning
>
> The eighties *were* a time of tinted reel and flouncy attire.

Comment: It's a matter of interpretation; *the '80s* can refer to a single era. For what it's worth *the eighties are returning* but *the eighties was a time* sound most natural to me.